# aws network loadbalancer target type instance but not preserve my source ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlb

I have an openshift cluster running on AWS with network loadbalancer as my ingress, however I found even though its target type is instance, it still not preserve my client source ip, instead, it use the private ip. This is not the same as describe in [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html)

My question is since it is not support to associate security group with NLB, but now only the NLB private IP reach my target, how can I limit the access with security group? Tried to associate security group on my target nodes, but in vain, I could only block the NLB private IP access, can someone please shed me some lights?

My NLB target group is instance type, shouldn't it preserv my source ip?

Below is the access log from nginx, it is private ip but with my source ip in the header

[image]

[image]

Comment: preserving IP in NLB depends on your NLB setup and listeners. You haven't provided such details.

Answer (score 1):

NLB does support [Client IP preservation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#client-ip-preservation). For TCP target groups it is disabled by default:

> you can enable or disable client IP preservation for **TCP** and TLS target groups using the **preserve_client_ip.enabled** target group attribute.

Comment: Thank you, I found a good way to control it from openshift, https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9d6ebf6c78f406d8639aae189901e47562418071/pkg/api/service/util.go